# Converting Hex Codes into Characters

Tags: php

Does PHP have a function that searches for hex codes in a string and converts them into their char equivalents?

For example - I have a string that contains the following

"Hello World\x19s"

And I want to convert it to

"Hello World's"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code will convert "Hello World\x27s" into "Hello World's".  It will convert "\x19" into the "end of medium" character, since that's what 0x19 represents in ASCII.

```
$str = preg_replace('/\\\\x([0-9a-f]{2})/e', 'chr(hexdec($1))', $str);
```

Comment: E_WARNING : type 2 -- preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead --

Answer (score 4):

Correct me if i'm wrong but i think you should change the callback like so:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\\\\x([0-9a-f]{2})/e', 'chr(hexdec(\'$1\'))', $str);
```

By adding the single quotes characters like '=' (\x3d) will be converted fine too.

Comment: E_WARNING : type 2 -- preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead --

Answer (score 2):

The /e will generate an error in current php advising to use preg_replace_callback. Try this:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\\\\x([0-9a-f]{2})/', function ($m) { return chr(hexdec($m[1])); },  $str );
```

Comment: The /e modifier in PHP does cause errors now. But your code still left the hexcodes in the string and did not convert to the character.

Answer (score 1):

/e Modifier causes PHP errors. It has been deprecated under new PHP updates. The correct way to convert hexcodes into characters is:

```
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8');
```

This will turn `&apos;` into **'** and `&amp;` into **&** etc